# Android KitKat latest version of Chrome

Tags: android, google-chrome

How can I find out the latest version of Chrome that I can run on KitKat Android (4.4x) please? Is it possible to grab the most recent versions APK from a newer OS install and copy to my KitKat device?

I need to determine the best way to run to run fullscreen without user intervention and there are varying supports for "fullscreen apis".

Comment: Questions about android general computing are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming. You may be able to get help on http://android.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

You can grab the [latest](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.android.chrome&hl=en) version of Chrome from Google Play, but it's backwards-compatible with KitKat and it won't change a single thing you're currently seeing on KitKat.

Here is the future [bleeding-edge](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.chrome.dev) version of Chrome, but this too won't solve your immediate testing problem.

Since you don't seem to have a Lollipop device with the right specs for what you're testing, you'll need to create a Lollipop Intel-based emulator for it and run it on your computer (an ARM-based emulator won't be sufficient, because it will be too slow).

If you need to simulate a slower cell phone internet connection with higher latency, you'll need to make that explicit when you configure your emulator, because one thing that developers forget is that their development machine usually has a very fast internet connection despite the fact that the emulator itself runs slower.